# Can print on screen but only print 1 thing in the file

Tags: c++

> Is there any problem when i write to file? It only print 1 thing in the file but it can print perfectly on screen. I have no idea on it. Can anyone help to solve it?This code will print a list of item that i insert from file

```
template <class T>
bool BST<T>::display2(BTNode<T> *cur,int order,int source)
{
ofstream out;
//if (!out)return false;
//if (cur == NULL) return false;
    if (order == 1 && source == 1){//display in ascending order and print to screen
        if (cur == NULL) return false ;
        display2(cur->left,order,source);
        cout << cur->item << ' ';
        display2(cur->right,order,source);
        return true;
    }
    if (order == 1 && source == 2){//display in ascending order and write to file
        out.open("student-info.txt");
        if(!out){
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Display Failed!!!\n";
            return false;
        }
        if (cur == NULL) return false;
        display2(cur->left, order, source);
        out << cur->item << ' ';
        display2(cur->right, order, source);
        return true;
    }
    if (order == 2 && source == 1){//display in descending order and print to screen
        if (cur == NULL) return false;
        display2(cur->right, order, source);
        cout << cur->item << ' ';
        display2(cur->left, order, source);
        return true;
    }
    if (order == 2 && source == 2){//display in descending order and print to file
        out.open("student-info.txt");
        if (!out){
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Display Failed!!!\n";
            return false;
        }
        if (cur == NULL) return false;
        display2(cur->right, order, source);
        out << cur->item << ' ';
        display2(cur->left, order, source);
        return true;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: chaotic code, hard to understand. Maybe you overwrite old file, , and must  'append' mode? BTW system("CLS") is for antipattern

Comment: You might consider moving "ofstream out;" to an outer level scope, so that the file does not close each time the function returns (note that cout does not close).  This requires you to plan when to close the file.

Comment: You might consider using "std::stringstream out" at some outer level scope.  Then plan where to close and output the contents to the ostream ... perhaps when the program ends (note that cout closes at the end of the program).

Answer (score 2):

You are rewriting content of your file with each line.
You need to open file for append. Change line

```
out.open("student-info.txt");
```

to

```
out.open("student-info.txt", std::fstream::app);
```

See [std::fstream::open](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/)